# Embed source document in output document

Tags: xml, xslt

Due to an... interesting... way a legacy system was implemented, XSLTs are used to generate HTML from an input XML document. And part of the output, which is needed when the pages POST back to the server, is the original XML document. e.g. if this is the source:

```
<page>
<head>Hello</head>
</page>
```

The output may look like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.sourceXml = '<page><head>Hello</head></page>';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(The XML was, until recently just emitted into the HTML, this is the best work around I could come up with without modifying the legacy system too much).

Which this brings me to the actual question: The existing XSLTs use the proprietary `<msxml:script>` tags to output the source XML into the output:

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
 <![CDATA[
    function fnGetXML(oRootList)
    {
        var sXML=oRootList.item(0).documentElement.xml
        return sXML;
    }
 ]]>
</msxsl:script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.pageXml = '<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="user:fnGetXML(.)" />';
</script>
```

Which this breaks in every other XSLT engine, along with newer versions of MSXML (without turning on special flags to allow running of scripts). Is there any way to accomplish this same task with straight XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a very easy way to do that. Just use `<xsl:copy-of select="/" />`. E.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      document.sourceXml = '<xsl:copy-of select="/" />';
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Now if your source XML could have single quotes in it, your javascript isn't going to be happy. I'm not sure I understand your purpose well enough to know whether this is important to you. In that case, you might do better just emitting the XML into the HTML; but you didn't want to do that and I'm not sure what your reasons were.

Comment: The main reason I don't want to do it is cross-browser compatibility. The application currently uses MSXML in-browser to manipulate this chunk of XML, which I'm trying to replace with jQuery's XML manipulation. My other option is using `<script type='text/xml'></script' to enclose the XML, but that seems to have issues on older versions of IE.